# why does my phpmyadmin on 000webhost not load

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Need a free web-host service for my android `php` scripts so i  Created an account on 000webhost yesterday and got a free domain,i tried the domain and its registered on server,I want to code some `php` scripts,I have created a database from MySQL on the site,when i click on enter `phpmyadmin` from the site,nothing loads,Am i suppose to upload some `php` files which configure the `phpmyadmin` in the pubic_HTML folder for it to start working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site can be Terrible at times message says "if you have just created new database it can take about 1 minute until phpMyadmin starts working!" But it took over 2 days for mine to start working,just tried it now and it works,You no longer have to manually install it as old tutorials suggest